Запятая перед как: до, во время и после того, как
В таком предложении: ...до, во время и после того, как разозлитесь.
Нужна ли запятая перед "как"?

Правильно:  ...до, во время и после того, как разозлитесь.
Пояснение
Временные союзы вида до того(,) как; после того(,) как и другие включают местоименную и союзную часть, но построены они по образцу определительного придаточного: до того момента, в который.
Такие союзы расчленяются в общем случае факультативно, как и все сложные союзы, но наличие однородных отношений способствует расчленению. Это общий принцип для сложных союзов по Розенталю:
 3. К условиям расчленения сложного союза относятся:
 4) включение первой части (соотносительного слова) в ряд 
 однородных членов предложения или параллельных 
 конструкций:Река приняла особенный вид потому, что вода 
 видна сквозь голые сучья, а еще более потому, что пропал от 
 холода водяной цвет (Акс.); 

